# Writing all outputs from nested applications to specific log file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script, `p.ps1`, which runs a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), `b.bat`. The batch file runs an application `MyApp.exe`. I also have a log file saved in local variable `$LogFile`.

Is there a way to configure the PowerShell script in a way that all nested applications including `MyApp.exe` will write to the same log file, without changing `b.bat` and `MyApp.exe`?

I've already tried:

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c b.bat" -Wait | Add-Content $LogFile
```

And

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c b.bat" -Wait | Out-File $LogFile -Append
```

Expected Results:

All outputs will be written to `$LogFile`, *I don't care whether outputs will be written to another log file, configured by the code of `MyApp.exe`*.

Actual Results:

All outputs of `b.bat` were written to `$LogFile`, but the outputs from `MyApp.exe` were written to another log file, configured by the code of `MyApp.exe`.

Comment: I have to ask, why are you using a [tag:batch-file], `b.bat`, to run an executable, `Myapp.exe`? Have you considered running `MyApp.exe` directly from the [tag:powershell] script, `p.ps1`?

Comment: Different apps will probably have different logs or may use a different format for writing info in logs. When you slam all this in the same logfile, it will most likely become an unstructured  mishmash of hard to read lines of text. You say `MyApp` uses a hardcoded logfile path (_"configured by the code of myApp"_), so if you want to change that file path, you need to rewrite/recompile this app or have it read its configuration from an easy to adjust config file. Apps may also block each other out when trying to write to the log at the same time. I personally doubt the benefit of this..

Comment: As a workaround, you could always read the other log file and append the contents to your current log file.

Comment: @AdminOfThings - That seems like a good idea, thanks. Can I print myApp to the screen/stdout and get everything from the powershell somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:
From the powershell file:
    $command = "& 'b.bat' 'arg1' 'arg2'" 
    Invoke-Expression $command | Add-Content $LogFile

From the myApp code, writing in C#:
Trace.WriteLine(msg);

This way, the c# program wrote everything to the screen. The powershell script caught the output and added it to the log file using Add-Content command.